# List of ignorable characters for string comparison

Tags: c#, string, unicode

Culture sensitive comparison in C# does not take into account "ignorable characters":

> Character sets include ignorable characters. The Compare(String, String) method does not consider such characters when it performs a culture-sensitive comparison. For example, a culture-sensitive comparison of "animal" with "ani-mal" (using a soft hyphen, or U+00AD) indicates that the two strings are equivalent, as the following example shows.

Where can I find complete list of such characters and maybe some details of comparison of strings containing ignorable characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All Unicode code points have a "default ignorable" property that is specified by the Unicode consortium; I would be very surprised if the .NET concept of ignorable characters is in any way different from the value of that property.

The definitive resource on which characters are default-ignorable is the Unicode standard, specifically section 5.21 ([link to chapter 5 PDF for Unicode v6.2.0](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/ch05.pdf)).

Comment: View http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/DerivedCoreProperties.txt and search for Default_Ignorable_Code_Point.