# Character after hyphen affects string.compare

Tags: c#, string-comparison

I would expect "2-" and "22" to always compare the same way, but changing the 3rd character changes the sort order.

```
string.Compare("2-1","22-", StringComparison.CurrentCulture) //-1
string.Compare("2-2","22-", StringComparison.CurrentCulture) //1
```

What on earth is happening here?

Our culture is en-US by the way.

Comment: *I would expect "2-" and "22" to always compare the same way* why so? they are never same right?

Comment: I would have thought that 2- Should equate to less than 22?, We should see -1 for both surely?

Comment: Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21454345/list-of-ignorable-characters-for-string-comparison).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6883c06.aspx):

> Character sets include ignorable characters. The `Compare(String, String, StringComparison)` method does not consider such characters when it performs a culture-sensitive comparison. To recognize ignorable characters in your comparison, supply a value of `StringComparison.Ordinal` or `OrdinalIgnoreCase` for the `comparisonType` parameter.

In your case, the hyphen is an ignorable character. In this case it means that the middle hyphen isn't taken into account. That means it actually compares `21` and `22` to `22-`, which will evaluate to `-1` and `1` respectively.

Comment: Haha thought as much. We need the current culture... and we need it to not ignore these characters. Any alternatives without using Ordinal? Thanks

Comment: Well, linguistic matching is quite difficult (what you have now). `Ordinal` is the other end of the spectrum. I don't expect to have anything in between, unless you write it yourself.

Comment: Thanks. For anyone looking to write their own, you can find a the ignored characters in Default_Ignorable_Code_Poin in this document:

http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/DerivedCoreProperties.txt

Comment: Surely you don't mean `21-` since that doesn't appear in either of the comparisons in the question.