# Why does CompareTo not sort my string using ASCII code ordering?

Tags: c#, string

In C# `"123-delete.json".CompareTo("123.json")` evaluates to `1`, meaning `"123-delete.json"` is to be sorted after `"123.json"`.

This is unexpected for me, as according to the ASCII table `.` comes after `-`.

[image]

I tried to browse the `CompareTo` implementation on GitHub, but it seems this logic is implemented in a native function (`InternalCompareString`).

Why does the `CompareTo` method not follow the ASCII ordering?

Also, is there a way to view the source code for native functions such as `InternalCompareString`?

Comment: In c# strings are sequences of _unicode_ characters. And the comparison is culture dependent, `CompareTo` withtout a `CultureInfo` parameter uses the current thread's `CultureInfo`.

Comment: @RenéVogt, so what exactly happens? How are they compared so that this result is produced?

Comment: Note that `string.CompareOrdinal` is probably what you're after here.

Comment: Unicode is not ASCII, so that's probably why you are getting these results. http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/software-technology/difference-between-unicode-and-ascii/

Comment: @dyukha 1) unicode is not ascii, so the order in the ascii-table is not relevant for the question 2) OP's strings are compared using their current thread's culture, I can't know which culture that is, but obivously one where "-" comes after "."

Comment: It can be confusing that `string`'s default algorithm for `CompareTo` is the current culture of the current thread, while its default for `Equals` is an ordinal comparison. Similarly for the implementations of `IComparable<string>` and `IEquatable<string>`.

Comment: @RenéVogt, 1) Unicode and ASCII match in the beginning. 2) No. I tested it here: https://rextester.com/ and `"-".CompareTo(".")` returns `-1`, while `"-a".CompareTo(".b")` returns `1`. So comparison rules are more complicated.

Comment: Be aware that ordinal comparison may return other values than just `-1`, `0`, or `1`. In fact it will return the difference between the two UTF-16 code units in question. All that is important is the sign of the return value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Character after hyphen affects string.compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44675770/character-after-hyphen-affects-string-compare)

Answer (score 4):

Use

```cs
string.Compare("123-delete.json", "123.json", StringComparison.Ordinal)
```

or

```cs
string.CompareOrdinal("123-delete.json", "123.json")
```

or

```cs
StringComparer.Ordinal.Compare("123-delete.json", "123.json")
```

In C# the comparison of strings is by default culture dependent and `StringComparison.Ordinal` lets the function compre the strings based on binary sort rules.

As @JeppeStigNielsen mentioned, the object returned by `StringComparer.Ordinal` implements the `IComparer<string>` interface, this lets you use this kind of sorting order in scenarios where you have a `SortedSet<string>`, `SortedList<string>` or any kind of "set" of strings that make use of an compare-object.

Comment: And a third syntax (`using System;`) is `StringComparer.Ordinal.Compare("123-delete.json", "123.json")`. The object `StringComparer.Ordinal` can be used as an `IComparer<string>` if you create a new `SortedDictionary<string, Xxx>` or similar (`SortedSet<string>`, `SortedList<string, Xxx>`, etc.).