# Why are some characters ignored when calling LastIndexOf?

Tags: c#, string, replace

Please take a look at these codes :

```
string str_to_find = "➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\r\n";
string str = "Nancy" + str_to_find;
if (str.EndsWith(str_to_find)) {
    str = Remove_Last_String(str, str_to_find);
}
```

And here is the method :

```
public static string Remove_Last_String(string Source, string Find) {
    int i = Source.LastIndexOf(Find);
    if (i >= 0) {
        string new_str = Source.Substring(0, i);
        return new_str;
    }
    else return Source;
}
```

I want `Nancy` for the output.
But method returns :
`Nancy➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖`
What is the problem about those strange characters & How can i fix it?

Comment: What is `➖`? Why is it in the string?

Comment: Please replace "➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖" with a string like "jhon". You will see every thing is ok & method returns "Nancy".I have a big string with many of this damn string "➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖".I want to remove the last one.

Comment: You are initializing `str_to_find` with these strange characters and then you are asking what these strange characters are?

Comment: @rad Those characters act like <hr> in stacloverflow. I have many of them in my dababase.

Comment: It's [heavy minus sign (U+2796)](https://graphemica.com/%E2%9E%96)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are messing with unusual Unicode characters. Or maybe they are messing with you. Please always specify string comparison style. Use this in your code:

`int i = Source.LastIndexOf(Find, StringComparison.Ordinal);`

The `StringComparison.Ordinal` forces the comparison of strings to ignore current culture settings. Apparently, the culture settings make the algorithm to behave differently than you/we want/expect.

Answer (score 4):

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_LastIndexOf_System_String_) state:

> Character sets include ignorable characters, which are characters that
>   are not considered when performing a linguistic or culture-sensitive
>   comparison. In a culture-sensitive search, if value contains an
>   ignorable character, the result is equivalent to searching with that
>   character removed.

➖ is an ignorable character, which explains why searching for `"\r\n"` or `"y➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\r\n"` behaves 'as expected', while `"➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\r\n"` does not.

*Using `StringComparison.Ordinal`, as shown by @AlKepp, will solve the issue since then the comparison is not culture sensitive.*

See also [List of ignorable characters for string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21454345/list-of-ignorable-characters-for-string-comparison).

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string str_to_find = "➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\r\n";
        string str = "Nancy" + str_to_find;
        if (str.EndsWith(str_to_find)) {
            str = Remove_Last_String(str, str_to_find);
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }
    
    public static string Remove_Last_String(string Source, string Find) {


        int i = Find.Length;
        int j = Source.Length;
        if (i >= 0) {
            string new_str = Source.Substring(0, j-i);
            return new_str;
        }
        else return Source;
    }
}
```

it works,
good luck

Comment: There is a lot of redundancy in you `Remove_Last_String`. Why not just write this? `public static string Remove_Last_String(string Source, string Find) => Source.EndsWith(Find) ? Source.Substring(0, Source.Length - Find.Length) : Source;`

Comment: you're right, I wanted to do something easy and close to the code shown in the question.